# .NET TreeView NodeMouseClick vs MouseClick vs Click events

Tags: vb.net, treeview, mouseclick-event

Could someone clarify what's the difference between these three events for the TreeView control in .NET?

Everyone of them is triggered when a node is clicked.

In practice, when should I use each of them over the others?

```
Private Sub TreeView_Devices_NodeMouseClick(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) _
                                                Handles TreeView_Devices.NodeMouseClick
    DisplaySignals(e.Node, Me)
End Sub

Private Sub TreeView_Devices_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) _
                                                Handles TreeView_Devices.MouseClick
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        MsgBox("Right Click")
    ElseIf e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        MsgBox("Left Click")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TreeView_Devices_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                                Handles TreeView_Devices.Click

End Sub
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

.NET distinguishes between Click and MouseClick because *some* controls allow firing a logical click with the keyboard.  Buttons and checkboxes for example, you click them with the space-bar.  Of course there's no mouse information available when the user operates the keyboard so that's why the Click event has a plain EventArgs instead of a MouseEventArgs.  You need to use MouseClick only when you care about the mouse location for some reason.

It doesn't apply to TreeView, it doesn't support "clicking" a node with the keyboard.

Next thing that matters is exactly *where* the user clicks.  Only some of the locations in a TreeView co-incide with a node.  So that's why there's NodeMouseClick, it only fires when the user clicked a node.  And doesn't fire when he clicked anywhere else, when expanding or collapsing a node for example.

It is a convenience event, it isn't actually necessary.  Because MouseClick is already good enough to *also* detect that the click was on a node.  But it requires more code, you have to use the [HitTest() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hittest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The event helps you avoid having to write that code.  Convenient.

Since you very rarely care about the user clicking on anything but nodes, you'd normally always favor NodeMouseClick.

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 and it seems that for me the MouseClick event behaves just like the NodeMouseClick event. Which is bad for me because I also want to deselect Nodes if the user clicks next to a node.